# select/sum of a column with different conditions in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$pos = select * from score_history where content_id = 6 && val = 1 
$neg = select * from score_history where content_id = 6 && val = -1
```

i want to get the `pos` and `neg` scores in one query 
but i dont want to use join

so perhaps some sort of IF/case statement ?

i've this but  as you can guess it fails

```
SELECT  count(*) as total , 
CASE 
    WHEN `val` =  1  THEN count(*) as `pos` 
    WHEN `val` = -1  THEN count(*) as `neg` 
END
FROM    score_history WHERE `content_id` = '46083' ";
```

is there any way to do this without using join or sub query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the flexibility of MySQL to handle booleans and integers:

```
SELECT  count(*) total, sum(val = 1) pos, sum(val = -1) neg
FROM    score_history 
WHERE   content_id = '46083';
```

Whenever the condition is true it is a 1. Otherwise a 0. No CASE needed nor GROUP BY.

Comment: That's slick, fun to learn tidbits like this since I spend almost all of my time in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Close!  A `CASE` statement doesn't return multiple columns, so you'll need 2 `CASE` statements and to wrap them in a `SUM()`:

```
SELECT  count(*) as total 
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN `val` =  1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `pos`
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN `val` =  -1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `neg` 
FROM    score_history WHERE `content_id` = '46083' ;
```

Comment: You should really have a `group by` on this.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, OP wants the total count, the count of `pos` and the count of `neg`, all items in the `SELECT` clause are aggregate functions, so no need for a `GROUP BY`

Comment: A fair point... I suppose I didn't really interpret the question that way. He said he wanted it in "one query" but didn't say he wanted "one result." That's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN `val` =  1  THEN 1 ELSE O END) AS pos_count, 
SUM(CASE WHEN `val` =  -1  THEN 1 ELSE O END) AS neg_count
FROM    score_history WHERE `content_id` = '46083';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Sorry I can't test, no database on this laptop.

```
select 
count(*) as total,
sum(case val when  1 then 1 else 0 end) as pos,
sum(case val when -1 then 1 else 0 end) as neg
from score_history
where content_id = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best answer (and you would certainly want an index on your val column assuming there are many rows in the table) but this should certainly work - also assuming you only have 1 and -1 as values:

```
SELECT count(*), val from score_history where content_id = 6 group by val;
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close; try the `SUM` function:

```
SELECT  count(*) as total 
      , sum(CASE WHEN `val` =  1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `pos` 
      , sum(CASE WHEN `val` = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `neg` 
FROM    score_history 
WHERE  `content_id` = '46083';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) 
from score_history  
where content_id = 6 && 
      (val = -1 or val=1) 
group by val
```

I think this statement should work but I have tested on DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT  count(*) as total ,
         count(case when val = 1 then 1 else null end) as pos,
         count(case when val = -1 then 1 else null end) as neg
 FROM    score_history 
 WHERE  `content_id` = '46083';
```

See **[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50832c/13/0)**

Answer (score -1):

Okay, a lot of these answers are close, but whenever you use an aggregate function you should use a `group by`.

```
SELECT  count(*) as total 
      , (CASE WHEN `val` >= 0 THEN 'positive' ELSE 'negative' END) as interpreted_value
END
FROM    score_history 
WHERE  `content_id` = '46083'
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN `val` >= 0 THEN 'positive' ELSE 'negative' END);
```

If you want to read up on how to use `group by` and aggregate functions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: interesting , i thought using group by would slow down my query ... apparently in this case i should use it

Comment: Actually, there is no need to use a group by.

Comment: This would result in 2 rows, one with `pos` count, one with `neg` count, and the total count wouldn't be displayed.  Just depends on what you're after.

Comment: Your query can be simplified enough not to need the group by and return only the 3 columns. See my answer.

Comment: Goat CO is right, it totally depends on what you're after. A `group by` will not slow down your query. I interpreted your question as you wanted one query to give you both of the values, but I didn't think you necessarily wanted them on the same row.